# button not calling the correct function

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, onclick

One of my table cells has the following content:

```
 <td>
     <span onclick="deleteProductVariants()" class="icon icon-trash"></span>
     <button class="done" onclick="update_Attributes(this)">Done</button>
</td>
```

My problem is that when I click the button, it seems like it's still `deleteProductVariants()` that is called. I really don't have any idea why- did anyone encounter this before?
 Note: none of them is in a form so it could have been submitted or anything. It's just that another function is called, weirdly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  When you click the `<button>`, it calls `deleteProductVariants()` instead of `update_Attributes`?  Is that right?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yep, it appears to do so

Comment: Comment span and try again, if things doing right, your span is overlapping the button.

Comment: I suggest you to use JQuery.

Comment: If I comment the first span, it works ok. However if I have it there, $("#button").click() still goes wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is JQuery example....

```
<td>
     <span id="deleteProductVariants" class="icon icon-trash"></span>
     <button class="done" id="update_Attributes">Done</button>
</td>

$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#deleteProductVariants').click(function(){
        alert($(this));
    });
    $('#update_Attributes').click(function(){
        alert($(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: It works now for some reason :) thanks. Still not sure why id didn't work with `onclick()`

Comment: Try putting you js method definition inside <head> tag.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your span is overlapping the button because of styling somehow (?)

Seeing as how your span has no text content and you're using it for an icon, I'm assuming you're giving it explicit widths and heights, thus no longer making it an inline element. Perhaps some margin stylings or something along those lines are causing the icon class to sit slightly over the button in this case.

Comment: nope, really. It's a really small icon and it's very distinct from the button. Also, if I do $("#buttonid").click(), the very same issue appears.
I can provide more context, but it's mostly just stuff that doesn't really have much to do with the action, information displayed to the user in tables.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this page? Also, are you sure you're doing a $("#buttonId") click? This button has no id.

Comment: It's local, and much stuff is server-generated :(

Comment: Have you inspected these elements in your debugger and seen for certain that their outlines are distinct and not overlapping? Also, again, are you sure you're getting this issue when programmatically clicking the button as well?

Comment: Yeah, I was getting the same issue when clicking it programatically. For some reason, binding it with jQuery as @BwithLove suggested works

Comment: You never really explained how you're clicking it programmatically by #buttonId when it hasn't an id ;)

Comment: I omitted that part, as well as inline style and other stuff, because I considered it irrelevant to the question